# How to pass jQuery scripts with codeIgneter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My goal is to pass a jQuery script through a model with CodeIgneter.

This is the view where I linked the jquery.js file

```
  <footer>
   <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
  </footer>      
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.js');?>">  </script>

   </div> <!-- /container -->
```

This is the model jquery

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Jquery extends CI_Model { 

public function test(){

return 

'<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submitForm").click(function(){
alert("test");
});

});

</script>';
}
}
```

In the controller I passed the script as following:

```
$this->load->model('jquery');
$data['testjs'] = $this->jquery->test();
$this->load->view('login/content',$data);
```

In the content view I echo the script:

```
...echo $testjs...
```

Unfortunately the script does not work as expected.

Comment: "*Unfortunately the script does not work as expected*". How *does* it work?

Comment: give us any error you are getting on the console?

Comment: You should really stop doing what you're trying to do. Javascript belongs to the view in my opinion, the mode l has completely different responsabilities

Comment: Hi Patrick, I also tried to put the js code in the view: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submitForm").click(function(){
alert("test");
});

});

</script>

But I get this error in the console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: I am getting this error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: then you need to include jquery library .

Comment: add this line in your header view if exists or in the current view    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

you need to include jquery library. Add this in your header view

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then this code in somewhere in view or header view

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#submitForm").click(function(){
    alert("this is working file ");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Dom crawler](https://github.com/dimabdc/PHP-Fast-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser) for that if you want to send html and jquery data pass through controller

https://github.com/dimabdc/PHP-Fast-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser

or else you can set in header view file as above answer given